# How to get the number of hours since the start of January 1 of the current year?

Tags: java, algorithm, date, datetime, jodatime

How can I get the number of hours since the start of January 1 of the current year in Java? I. e. first hour of January 1 = 0001
Can I accomplish this with JodaTime or any other lib?
Thanks,

Comment: What time zone are you interested in? And are you interested in *elapsed* hours, or "logical" hours? (Imagine it's midnight on January 3rd, and in the relevant time zone one hour was skipped on January 2nd due to a DST transition - do you want the answer to be 47 or 48?) Have you tried anything yet? (This is a reasonably simple problem using java.util.*, java.time.* or Joda Time...)

Comment: You basically have two problems, one, how to create a date instance that is the first day of the current year and then how to calculate the duration between it and now.  In Java 8's Time API, you can take advantage of `LocalDateTime#withDayOfYear`, then it's just a matter of calculating the duration, which there are plenty of examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)):

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(
  LocalDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now().getYear(), 1, 1, 0, 0), 
  LocalDateTime.now())
```

I think this is self-explenatory

Comment: Also, I'd avoid starting number constants with an additional `0`. For `0` to `7` it may work because they have the same value in decimal and octal, but it creates a big chance for bugs on future changes.

Comment: FYI, this Answer addresses standard hours, and ignores Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other such anomalies/issues.

Comment: @JuanLopes, since the numbers represent date and time, the values follow the convention of these types. you know, like 2015-01-01 00:00

Comment: @sharonbn Yes, but what if you wanted to create a LocalDateTime with the date 2015-09-09? `LocalDateTime.of(2015, 09, 09, 00, 00)`? This just doesn't compile.

Comment: @JuanLopes, I see what you mean. I googled a bit and realized that  leading zeros cause the compiler to treat the literals as octal type. fixed the answer and thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 5):

Use the Java 8 API for date/time

```
    LocalDateTime hournow = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime startOfYear = LocalDateTime.of(hournow.getYear(), 1, 1, 0, 0);
    long hoursBetween = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(startOfYear, hournow);
    System.out.println("hours between: " + hoursBetween);
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that many users will rather expect to take dst-effects into account:

```
ZoneId zi = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"); // example

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zi);
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of(now.getYear(), 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, zi);
long realDelta = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start, now);
System.out.println("hours between: " + realDelta); // 5386

// another way using Instant
Instant i2 = now.toInstant();
Instant i1 = start.toInstant();
System.out.println(i1); // 2014-12-31T23:00:00Z
System.out.println(i2); // 2015-08-13T09:55:53.353Z
System.out.println("duration=" + i1.until(i2, ChronoUnit.HOURS)); // 5386
```

The proposed solutions so far based on `LocalDateTime` without any time zone would yield a different result (here only a nominal and not a physical Duration):

```
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.of(ldt2.getYear(), 1, 1, 0, 0);
long hoursBetween = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(ldt1, ldt2);
System.out.println("hours between: " + hoursBetween); // 5385
```

In case of `java.util.GregorianCalendar` the result will be the same as for Java-8 based on `ZonedDateTime`. Other libraries also offer similar results but I leave out such details because it is more important to understand the **impact of timezones on your result**.